# Prettier не форматирует

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

Prettier(vs code) перестал форматировать в определённом файле. Вчера он ещё работал там. Проверил в других проектах - он работает. Раньше сталкивался с такой проблемой, но она фиксилась тем, что надо было редактируемый файл открыть в рабочей области. Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Answer (score 1):

Обычно форматирование не применяется когда в коде есть синтаксическая ошибка. При этом так же отключается подсветка ошибок форматирования. Надо найти подсвеченную ошибку и исправить её.

Answer (score 0):

В коде был пропущен `</div>`, поэтому Prettier не работал.